# Why they always use while(true) loop for the process in process synchronization chapter?

Tags: multithreading, process, synchronization, operating-system

I am reading the textbook Operating Systems Concepts by Abraham Silberschatz et al. I found that whey almost use while(TRUE) loop for all the processes that need to be synchronized in the the chapter Process Synchronization. Some of them make sense to me, e.g. dining philosopher problem use while(TRUE) loop because philosophers need to "think" all the time, so its process needs to do a while(TRUE) loop to emulate this. But some of them doesn't make sense to me. Let's take reader-writer problem for an example, the sample codes given in the text book puts both reader and writer processes in a while loop.

Why? Why reader process reads something after and after? Why don't they just finish/exit after they read what it wanted to read? In my understanding, are they doing this to simply emulate there are multiple same processes running at the same time?

```
// solution code of the textbook for first reader-writer problem

// writer process
do {
   wait(wrt);
   // writing is performed
   signal(wrt);
}while(TRUE)

// reader process
do {
  wait(mutex);
  readCount++;
  if(readCount==1)
     wait(wrt);
  signal(mutex);
  //reading is performed
  wait(mutex);
  readCount--;
  if(readCount==0)
    singal(wrt);
  signal(mutext);

}while(TRUE)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `while (true)` is a good idea to indicate an infinite loop (providing that particular language has no special construct to express infinite loops), because the reader is immediatelly informed what's going on when reading the source code from top to bottom.

Using an infinite loop in a reader / writer, or consumer / producer scenario, looks reasonable too. Frequently a piece of software (or its component) is designed to perform a certain task repeatedly. To uncover the reason for choosing an infinite loop in a particular case would require a lot more detailed knowledge of the scenario.